# Angular 2 enable an input box from the component using a checkbox value from template

Tags: angular

sorry for the question title, can't figure out a better one.

So, i have this function that is triggered by a checkbox true/false value:

```
setReward(): void {
const rewardControl = this.myFormLost.get('reward');
if (this.lostRewardCheck === true) {
  rewardControl.setValidators(Validators.required);
  rewardControl.enabled  // WHAT GOES HERE
  this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.rewardAmountFocus.nativeElement, 'focus', []);
} else {
  rewardControl.clearValidators();
  this.myFormLost.patchValue({
    reward: ''
  });
}
rewardControl.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

How i can enable the 'reward' input box? Default state is disabled, when the user marks check box as true, i don't know how to enable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of these

```
this.renderer.setElementProperty(this.rewardAmountFocus.nativeElement, 'enabled', true);
this.renderer.setElementAttribute(this.rewardAmountFocus.nativeElement, 'enabled', 'true');
```

or set `'disabled', false`

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Renderer-class.html

Comment: that worked using `setElementProperty`, thanks. The `this.renderer.setElementAttribute(this.rewardAmountFocus.nativeElement, 'enabled', true);
` fires a argument of type boolean cannot be assigned to parameter of type string.

Comment: Sorry, `setElementAttribute` expects a string (should be `'true'`)